# How do I create configuration object in a unit test in my dropwizard application?

Tags: java, unit-testing, dropwizard

We have a configuration class in our dropwizard application:

```
public class MyConfiguration extends Configuration
```

I need to create the real configuration object in my unit test by reading the yaml file. Any pointers would be useful?

It looks like when the dropwizard app is started, the application will read the yaml configuration file and create MyConfiguration but I want a real (not mocked) configuration object while running a simple unit test.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following to the build section of your pom to include the YAML configuration file as a test resource:

```xml
<testResources>
    <testResource>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
    </testResource>
    <testResource>        
        <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>config.yml</include>
        </includes>
    </testResource>
</testResources>
```

Then in your unit test create a Configuration object like so:

```java
import javax.validation.Validator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import io.dropwizard.jackson.Jackson;
import io.dropwizard.jersey.validation.Validators;
import io.dropwizard.configuration.YamlConfigurationFactory;

// ...

@Test
public void test() {
    final ObjectMapper objectMapper = Jackson.newObjectMapper();
    final Validator validator = Validators.newValidator();
    final YamlConfigurationFactory<MyConfiguration> factory = new YamlConfigurationFactory<>(MyConfiguration.class, validator, objectMapper, "dw");

    final File yaml = new File(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("config.yml").getPath());
    final MyConfiguration configuration = factory.build(yaml);

    // ...

}
```

Comment: This method is documented on the Dropwizard on their [testing page](http://www.dropwizard.io/1.2.2/docs/manual/testing.html#) under the section *Testing Configurations*.  For me, I didn't need to make the pom.xml change @RCB mentioned to get it to work.

Comment: @mikehwang In that case, your YAML configuration file must already be in a test resource directory. My example is assuming that the YAML file is at the base directory of the project.